# What are some proven approaches to reporting startup errors in a Web API application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I'm starting a new Web API project, and have installed Elmah. Reporting exceptions seems straight-forward in the context of HTTP requests. But what about exceptional things that happen during application startup? Elmah has a mechanism for manually logging exceptions, but is this a wise approach? I get an uneasy feeling that I'm doing something that's not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

ELMAH is a great choice for logging uncaught exceptions in Web API as well as manual logging of errors. If you haven't already, you should take a look at [Elmah.Contrib.WebApi](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi), which both logs Web API errors automatically but also contains an [ExceptionLogger](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi/blob/master/src/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/ElmahExceptionLogger.cs) for Web API, which will log errors during initialization as well.

With that said, ELMAH probably isn't the right tool for every logging scenario. If you want to log information, debug and verbose messages, you can combine the use of ELMAH with a log framework of your choice. I personally love [Serilog](http://serilog.net/), but there are other choices like log4net and NLog. All are pretty easy to install in Web API.

Actually, I wrote a blog post some months ago, where I tried to sum up the [ASP.NET Error Logging Best Practices](http://blog.elmah.io/asp-net-error-logging-best-practices/), that you can read. For more information about the diffferences between ELMAH and logging framework, I also wrote [ELMAH vs log4net](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-vs-log4net/), which also covers other logging frameworks than log4net.

Comment: Thanks, Elmah.IO seems like a great solution if serious logging is required

Comment: elmah.io is an alternative to the ones I mention above. elmah.io supports both error logging and other types of logging through log4net, NLog, Serilog etc.

Comment: I already use NLog for other apps, but it's undesirable that it's not unified with Elmah (i.e. have to manage two separate error reporting mechanisms). Sounds like Elmah.IO unifies things for you.

Comment: It does for sure :)